# Laravel 4 Mail::queue not using the right environment

Tags: php, email, url, laravel, laravel-4

I've been working on this website for a while and just recently finished and wanted to "go live". I have two environments in my production server: staging and production. Both environments seem to work fine, each of them with their own configurations.

The weird problem I'm facing is when sending an email using Mail::queue, the views that are being picked up by the mail class are the ones in the staging environment and not the ones in production, which also seems to make the class think that it's in the staging environment. So all the URL's in the received email (all configured in the view to be like URL::to('route')) point to the staging environment instead of production. So if staging is like staging.domain.com and production www.domain.com, the links in my emails sent from the production environment are staging.domain.com (the contrary doesn't happen)

This does not occur with the rest of the links in the website, only with emails.

I haven't been able to figure this one out, and I was hoping someone around here can help me out!

Thanks!

PS: I've already tried clearing out the views in the storage folder, the cache using artisan cache:clear

Comment: What queue driver are you using and what command do you use to start your queue workers?

Comment: Also, what does your `detectEnvironment()` function look like?

Comment: App::environment() returns PRODUCTION right before calling Mail::queue but it returns STAGING inside the email

Comment: smtp is the mail driver, and for the queues I'm using beanstalkd and supervisord

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to the **supervisord** configuration. Basically there was only one queue and it was the staging one.

Resolved the issue by updating the **supervisord.conf** with the production queue info.

Comment: I'm having this problem currently - how did you managed to fix it, exactly? :-) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no HTTP request associated with queued jobs, they must get the application url from a config setting. This config setting is the `url` key in the `app.php` configuration file.

My guess is that you have set the `url` key in the `app/config/app.php` file to `staging.domain.com`.

You can override configuration files per environment by creating a subdirectory in the `app/config` directory with the environment name. I prefer to leave the php files in the `app/config` directory alone, and make any config changes to environment specific config files.

As an example, one solution to your problem would be to create the following files (assuming your environment names are "staging" and "production"):

**app/config/staging/app.php**

```
return array(
    'url' => 'http://staging.domain.com',
);
```

**app/config/production/app.php**

```
return array(
    'url' => 'http://www.domain.com',
);
```

You can read more about environment configuration [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/configuration#environment-configuration).

Comment: Thanks for your response Patricus, but the environments are already configured the way you suggest. I have two separate "staging" and "production" folders under config, and under each an app.php pointing to their respective URL's